# What is meaning and use of the method having "=(parameters)" after method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following method in one of my module

```
def current_user
end

def current_user=(new_user)
end
```

What i wanted to know is what is the use of the method `current_user=(new_user)`.
I also like to know following things
1. Can we declare such methods in model, controller
2. how to call such methods
3. documentation link for such things

Comment: How could you accrue 700+ points in [tag:ruby] + [tag:ruby-on-rails] and not know this? It's basic ruby stuff.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev:- I am sorry it may be a basic ruby stuff but this is first time i came across such method, and i don't mind asking such question w/o having a fear of down votes.I simply follows "He who ask a question is a fool for five minutes he who does not ask a question remains a fool forever". BTW thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all variables in ruby are private. It's possible to access them only via methods (often named geters and setters). So

```
def current_user
end
```

is getter and

```
def current_user=(new_user)
end
```

is setter

To better understand, you can read this article:
http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/oop2/

UPD: Such methods you can use in controllers, models - in any class

Comment: To be pedantic, declaring a method named `xyz=` is just that. It's a method named `xyz=`. It just so happens that Ruby expects an argument when you call `receiver.xyz=`, which is why it makes more sense for  `xyz=` to expect 1 parameter. You can declare `xyz=` to expect 0 parameters, or two parameters, but if you do so, you can only call it using `receiver.send(:xyz=, ...)`